# New to pgAdmin III -- Can't view databases

Tags: heroku, pgadmin

I just installed the most recent version of pgAdmin III (1.20 installed on Windows 8). I haven't used this software before, so I may be overlooking something simple.

I'm able to connect ok (at least to heroku, with my DB name in the 'maintenance db' field). Additionally, when I select the server in pgAdmin, it shows my DB name listed on the right hand side, along with the rest of my credentials.

That said, it shows that there 0 databases for my server. Should I click 'databases(0)', I get this error:

```
Error: Column datconfig does not exist.
```

In my Googling, it seems that this error typically happens when users are running an older version of pgAdmin. I'm running the most recent, though .

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with Windows 8. I just installed the Mac client on a laptop, and everything went fine.